# How to solve a change detection issue with nested reactive form components?

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-components

I have the following (simplified) scenario:

- A component that has a (reactive) form with nested components acting as form controls
- One of the nested components is called `SelectComponent` that offers a `<select>` tag
- The `SelectComponent` implements `NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR` and `NG_VALIDATORS`
- The parent component supplies the select options as input field to the `SelectComponent`

This works well so far, but I have issues when I want to automatically update the behavior in the inner `SelectComponent` based on the following:

- If there are multiple options or if the control is not required, do nothing
- If there is only one option and if the control is required, automatically select the (only) option.

I implemented the `ngOnChanges` event in order to achieve the above.

Here is a minimal example on Stackblitz that is nearly working:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ohdb71?file=src%2Fapp%2Fselect%2Fselect.component.ts

But then, I have problems with change detection in the main component. As you can see, the main component does not update the `user.value` to Walter automatically, even though the inner `SelectComponent` has set this value and also announced it to the outer component. Consequently, the main component thinks that the value is not set and marks the form control with an error (required).

Oddly enough, the code works (without `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError`) whenever I move the code `<app-select [formControlName]="'user'" [options]="userOptions"></app-select>` to the top of the file.

How can I fix this problem in the `SelectComponent` in a way such that the outer component does not have to implement any more logic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TLDR: you can find your working example here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-f8fiux

There are several steps to be done to make it work:

Modify ***writeValue*** method. writeValue is the ***input*** of your custom component, so it shouldn't call ***onChange*** method (which is ***output*** of the component), otherwise it can lead to incorrect interaction.

```
writeValue(value: any): void {
    this.selectFormControl.setValue(value, { emitEvent: false });
}
```

Here `emitEvent: false` is passed so as to not trigger change event of `selectFormControl`.
To understand logic of Value Accessors I recommend [this article](https://indepth.dev/posts/1055/never-again-be-confused-when-implementing-controlvalueaccessor-in-angular-forms).

---

Modify ***ngOnChange*** method. It should set inner value of your component (through ***writeValue***) and then emit it for outer consumer (through ***onChange***). For onChange you have to schedule either microtask (Promise.resolve) or macrotask (setTimeout), otherwise the data will be emitted in the same change detection cycle, causing *ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError*

```
ngOnChanges(simpleChanges: SimpleChanges): void {
  if (simpleChanges.options) {
    if (this.options.length === 1) {
      if (this.selectFormControl.value !== this.options[0]) {
        this.writeValue(this.options[0]);
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.onChange(this.options[0]);
        });
      }
    } else {
      this.writeValue(null);
    }
  }
}
```

---

It's better not to mix Reactive Forms and Template-driven forms, so I recommend you to get rid of `(ngModelChange)="onChange($event)"` in template as it's *asynchronous data flow* and needs more complicated handling. Instead of that, you can add a simple subscription in constructor (don't forget to unsubscribe, here I omitted it)

```
constructor(private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) {
  this.selectFormControl.valueChanges.subscribe((value) => {
    this.onChange(value);
  });
}
```

You can find detailed information about *async* and *sync* flow in [Angular docs](https://angular.io/guide/forms-overview#data-flow-in-forms)

Comment: Thanks for your amazing help. You actually got it totally correct, I incorrectly remembered the implementation of `writeValue`. Thus, it didn't have the correct functionality. The rest of your post makes absolute sense then. No worries about subscribe/unsubscribe, the Stackblitz is a minimal example of my problem anyway.